# Improve git diffs when renaming and changing files

Tags: typescript, git, github, diff, github-codereviews

I'm converting quite a lot of code from JavaScript to TypeScript, which means:

1. rename files from .js to .ts
2. add type annotations etc

Of course in many cases, such a refactoring can be substantial, and you might rewrite code completely to take benefit of TS (or because it's just old).
But quite often I find myself starting with the simple steps above.
Since I'm a bit obsessed with code reviews to avoid typos and silly mistake when migrating code, I prefer to thoroughly review my code in GitHub PRs. However, when a file has been renamed AND slightly changed, GitHub frequently just gives up and displays it as one deleted file and one added file. This means that a 500 line file will have to be reviewed without any context, which is completely useless!

I've found a workaround which is to

1. make a single commit with all files I intend to migrate, where I only rename the files and nothing else (code is broken at this point of course)
2. make a second commit with all the TS adaptations

The I review the PR and exclude the first commit, which means I will be reviewing quite small changes (`require` -> `import`, type annotations on functions and variables, etc). The bulk of the file content is unchanged.

However this is painful because quite often you start a migration task and you migrate some files at a time, and you don't know at first which exact files you will migrate when this PR is done. So sometimes when I'm done, I've created a new branch, manually renamed the migrated files to .ts, commited that change, then copied the code changes from the work branch using `git checkout migration-branch -- src` and make a second commit.

This is just a frustrating workflow. Is there a way to hint to git or GitHub that a file was renamed and modified so that it doesn't think that the JS file was deleted and an entirely unrelated TS file was added? Or is there some other trick?

Comment: `git diff` has an option [-M](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Mltngt) to control whether a change should be considered as rename or a pair of delete and add. I don't know if Github has a similar option on its review page.